# How do i hyperlink in my iPhone Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want a hyperlink in my iPhone Application, for example like in HTML:

```
<a href="www.yahoo.com"> Click here </a>
```

How can i do this in Objective-C?

The most important thing is that I don't want to show the actual link, I just want to show some text like "click here" and then it loads a link.

I'm currently using the below code. But as i told you I don't want to show the link instead I want something like "click here".

```
textView.text = @"http://stackoverflow.com";

textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a button. Would UIButton not work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
UIButton *btnFaceBook = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
[btnFaceBook setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 290, 280, 30)];
[btnFaceBook setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[btnFaceBook.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
[btnFaceBook addTarget:self action:@selector(followFacebook) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnFaceBook setTitle:@"Click Here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[contentView addSubview:btnFaceBook];
```

below is the function to open the link:

```
-(void) followFacebook{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com/"]];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Apple has a [writeup](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1487/_index.html) that should tell you everything you need to know to do this.

The summary is that you make a category on `NSAttributedString` so that you can pass it a string and a URL, and it will create an attributed string that looks like a hyperlink (blue and underlined, for example) and has the URL as an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this with a `UIButton`. Just set the title of the button as "click here" or whatever you want and open the link when the user clicks on the button.

```
-(void)buttonClicked {
// code to open link
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by hiding the link?

Comment: if u use to about html then u know this..<a href=www.yahoo.com somelink> CLICK HERE </a>

Comment: @Devang: Actually 7KV7 deserves to be selected as the answer because he beats @Prabh by 2:30 minutes.